# Visualizar mi inicio en Navigation Drawer

Tags: fragment, navigation

Intento que el navigation drawer inicie y lo primero que visualice sea la primera opción del menú (La primera opcion se llama inicio) sin necesidad que el usuario lo seleccione. Les dejo el código si pueden ayudarme:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ChatAlumno.OnFragmenItemSelectedListener,
        ActividadesAlumno.OnFragmenItemSelectedListener, AsesoriasAlumno.OnFragmenItemSelectedListener, ManualAlumno.OnFragmenItemSelectedListener, InicioAlumno.OnFragmenItemSelectedListener, DepartamentosAlumno.OnFragmenItemSelectedListener {

    //Flipper
    public static  final  String BASE_URL = "https://pitav2.000webhostapp.com/Imagenes_app/ViewFlipper/";
    private AdapterViewFlipper adapterViewFlipper;

    private TextView tvControl, tvCorreo;
    private UserInfo userInfo;
    private UserSession userSession;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        View header = ((NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).getHeaderView(0);
        ImageView foto_perfil = (ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.image_menu);


        userInfo        = new UserInfo(this);
        userSession     = new UserSession(this);
        tvControl       = header.findViewById(R.id.tv_numero_control_header);
        tvCorreo        = header.findViewById(R.id.tv_correo_header);
        String control = userInfo.getKeyControl();
        String correo    = userInfo.getKeyCorreo();
        tvControl.setText(control);
        tvCorreo.setText(correo);


        adapterViewFlipper = findViewById(R.id.adapterView);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<FlipperImages> call = service.getFlipperImages();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<FlipperImages>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FlipperImages> call, Response<FlipperImages> response) {
                ArrayList<FlipperImage> flipperI = response.body().getFlipperI();
                FlipperAdapter adapter = new FlipperAdapter(getApplicationContext(),flipperI);
                adapterViewFlipper.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapterViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);
                adapterViewFlipper.startFlipping();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FlipperImages> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        @SuppressLint("CutPasteId") NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        //Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        boolean FragmentTransaction = false;
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.inicio) {
            fragment = new InicioAlumno();
            FragmentTransaction = true;
        } else if (id == R.id.perfil) {
            fragment = new PerfilAlumno();
            FragmentTransaction = true;
        
        } else if (id == R.id.chat) {
            fragment = new ChatAlumno();
            FragmentTransaction = true;
        } else if (id == R.id.manual){
            fragment = new ManualAlumno();
            FragmentTransaction = true;

        } else if (id == R.id.centrodeactividades) {
            fragment = new ActividadesAlumno();
            FragmentTransaction = true;

        } else if (id == R.id.asesorias) {
            fragment = new AsesoriasAlumno();
            FragmentTransaction = true;

        } else if (id == R.id.departamentos) {

        } else if (id == R.id.soporte) {
            fragment = new AsesoriasAlumno();
            FragmentTransaction = true;

        } else if (id == R.id.sesion){
            userSession.setLoggedin(false);
            userInfo.clearUserInfo();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class));
            finish();

        }

        if(FragmentTransaction) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main, fragment)
                    .commit();

            item.setChecked(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

Comment: segun lo que entiendo es que al abrir la app ya te mueste por defecto la primera opcion del menu, es correcto? si es asi te puedo ayudar como hacerlo. de lo contrario se mas explicativo.

Comment: Si, que muestre el fragment de la primera opcion, yo lo llame inicio y quiero que al abrir la app sea lo primero que se visualice

Comment: ya le deje la respuesta mas abajo, eso pogale dentro del **onCreate** y le deberia funcionar. si es asi, por favor emarquele como respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que desea es mostrar el contenido de la primera opcion por defecto en la ventana ponga las siguientes lineas dentro del metodo **onCreate** despues de las siguientes lineas de su codigo:

**@SuppressLint("CutPasteId") NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);**

y antes de cerrar la llave **}**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main,new InicioAlumno()).commit();
```

Comment: Me ha servido pero he visto que muchos agregan con un switch, lo intente pero me marca error; sin embargo muchas gracias por la respuesta :)